# Cannot parse multiple files with logstash input "file"

Tags: windows, logstash

I am trying to parse a folder with logstash on windows but I have some strange results.

I have a file `samplea.log` with the following content :

```
1
2
3 
4 
5
```

I have a file `sampleb.log` with the following content:

```
6
7 
8 
9 
10
```

This is my config file:

```
input {
  file  {
    path=> "C:/monitoring/samples/*.log"
  }
}
output { 
  stdout { debug => "true" }
  elasticsearch {    
    protocol => "transport"
    host => "127.0.0.1"
  }  
}
```

For unknown reasons, the events displayed on my console are 6,7,8,9 and the same events are stored in elasticsearch. The last line of my file sampleb is ignored and the whole file samplea is ignored.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try to delete the .sincedb at yout $HOME directory. In window you can try to find it at your User folder.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I've patched original logstash (1.4.2) distribution with the filewatch-0.6.1 gem (original is filewatch-0.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Logstash is delimiting lines with return character. Make sure you hit enter on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Known bug, the inner library tracks the file with inode. On Windows the library use a function that always return 0. In your case, I think logstash reads the simpleb.log, then reads simplea.log from index 6, which is end-of-file.
Bug tracked here : https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/2